# C# Reflection, using MakeGenericMethod with method that has the 'new()' type constraint

Tags: c#, reflection, generics, generic-method

I am trying to use the MethodInfo MakeGenericMethod as follows:

```
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            object output = null;
            var method = typeof (ContentTypeResolver).GetMethod("TryConstruct");
            var genmethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            var arr = new object[] { from, output };
            if ((bool)genmethod.Invoke(null, arr))
                return (IThingy)arr[1];
        }
```

Against the following generic method:

```
    public static bool TryConstruct<T>(string from, out IThingy result) where T : IThingy, new()
    {
        var thing = new T();
        return thingTryConstructFrom(from, out result);
    }
```

The problem I having is that I get an arguement exception on the MakeGenericMethod line as the type I am passing is not 'new()'

Is there a way round this??
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You can only make closed constructed TryConstruct methods with type parameters that meet the `IThingy` and `new` constraints.  Otherwise you'd be defeating the TryConstruct contract: what would happen when you called TryConstruct and it hit the `new T()` line?  There wouldn't *be* a T() constructor, so you'd have violated type safety.

You need to check that type has a public default constructor before passing it to MakeGenericMethod.  If you need to instantiate types with a nondefault constructor, you need to create a new method or a TryConstruct overload, perhaps one which uses Activator.CreateInstance instead of `new T()`.